# DrawerLayout overlapped by another view

Tags: android, user-interface, drawerlayout

I implemented a Navigation Drawer as explained here https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html 
I inserted the DrawerLayout xml code snippet just below the  tag and above the others app views.
At runtime when open the Navigation Drawer the behind view is still clickable and I cant use the Navigation Drawer
I think I've to adjust the xml layout but I don't know how..

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sky">
    <com.example.sp1d3r.weatheralarm.CustomDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </com.example.sp1d3r.weatheralarm.CustomDrawerLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/cityTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Assuming `CustomDrawerLayout` is a subclass of the standard `DrawerLayout`, it needs to be the root View in your layout.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your answer! Yes it is a subclass. What do you mean with root view? I've to put all other view as child of  CustomDrawerLayout? is this the right way? Have you an example? thx